# Getting find: paths must precede expression error with subprocess.check_output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get count of files in a directory. Here is the code:

```
import subprocess
op = subprocess.check_output(['find', '/home/my-path', '-type', 'f', '|', 'wc', '-l'])
print(op)
```

I am getting following error:

```
find: paths must precede expression: |
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chk.py", line 42, in <module>
    op = subprocess.check_output(['find', '/ml/cadv1/nipatel/copied-repo', '-type', 'f', '|', 'wc', '-l'])
  File "/ml/tools/opensource/python3/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 629, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/ml/tools/opensource/python3/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 711, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['find', '/home/my-path', '-type', 'f', '|', 'wc', '-l']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Can someone point me the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pipe with `subprocess` like that.
Instead, you read the `stdout` of find and then pass that as the `stdin` to a new `Popen` with `wc -l`.

```
import subprocess
term = subprocess.Popen(['find', '/home/my-path', '-type', 'f'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
find_out = term.communicate()[0]
term2 = subprocess.Popen(['wc', '-l'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
op = term2.communicate(find_out)[0].decode()
print(op)
```

Longer explanation:

First, we open a terminal session with `subprocess.Popen`. Then we redirect the input/output using `subprocess.PIPE`, otherwise, it will print the result out. To access those, we can use `stdout, stderr = term.communicate(stdin)`. We repeat to pass our data to `wc`.

Note that, when we already have our data in python, we could also calculate the number of lines inside python.

```
import subprocess
term = subprocess.Popen(['find', '/home/my-path', '-type', 'f'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
find_out = term.communicate()[0]
print(len(find_out.decode().splitlines()))
```